# Can I integrate container class methods with those of a generic interface?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, interface

I have a container class `Foo<TInterface>` which takes an arbitrary interface type parameter and a string "strCode" in its constructor.

Upon instantiating Foo, strCode is compiled via the CSharpCodeProvider and, through Reflection, the appropriate type is located within the newly compiled code, then cast to TInterface type and hoisted within Foo to a property TInterface bar.

This works fine and the client can access foo.bar no problem. However, Foo also contains (among other methods) a method named Recompile, which basically takes and compiles a new code string in the aforementioned manner. This also works fine, but it means that the client ends up with a Foo API where methods are organised something like:

```
foo.bar.MakeCoffee
foo.bar.DoMagic
foo.Recompile
```

**I would instead prefer:**

```
foo.MakeCoffee
foo.DoMagic
foo.Recompile
```

In other words, I would like to return a class instance with top level access to both the generic interface methods AND the Foo API methods.

Ideally, it would be nice to return an instance of `Foo<TInterface>` but I understand C# generics do not permit this. I would be happy to post code if required, but first want to make sure I am not barking up the wrong tree due to C#'s static type nature.

Comment: What version of C#?  You could use the new dynamic language support in C# 4 to make this work.

Comment: I would prefer to use C# 3.5 if possible, if only because (from my experience) this version of CSharpCodeProvider compiles about 15% faster than 4.0. However, I would be keen to enquire about a dynamic solution if it is not too convoluted. Would you have any recommendations as to where I should look or the general approach I should take?

Comment: Here are some examples: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/19/dynamic-in-c-4-0-creating-wrappers-with-dynamicobject.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use a proxy library like [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/hamiltondynamicproxy.aspx) or [linfu](http://code.google.com/p/linfu/).

What is the goal you are trying to achieve? Do you want to do AOP?